# FireMonkey: form embedded in a form embedded in a form

Tags: forms, layout, firemonkey, c++builder

I have three forms: Form1 in which is embedded Form2 in which is embedded Form3.
The first level of embedding works, the second not.

In Form1 I have a TPanel (Form1Pn) and a button with this code in the click event:

```
Form2->Form2Layout->Parent = Form1Pn;
Form2->Form2Layout->Visible = true;
```

In Form2 I have a TLayout (Form2Layout) aligned allclient, a TRectangle aligned allclient just to set a background color, a TPanel (Form2Pn) and a button with this code in the click event:

```
Form3->Form3Layout->Parent = Form2Pn;
Form3->Form3Layout->Visible = true;
Form3->Show();
```

Form2 BorderStyle is Sizeable.

In Form3 I have a TLayout (Form3Layout) aligned allclient and a TRectangle aligned allclient just to set a background color.
Form3 BorderStyle is None.

When I click the button in Form1, Form2 appears inside Form1Pn as expected.
When I click the button in Form2, Form3 appears outside Form1.

I'm not familiar with FireMonkey and I don't understand what I am missing, someone can help me?

Thanks

UPDATE.
I don't know how to attach zipped code, perhaps I can't, so I post the code here:

TForm1.cpp

```
#include <fmx.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "TForm1.h"
#include "TForm2.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.fmx"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    Form2->Form2Layout->Parent = Form1Pn;
    Form2->Form2Layout->Visible = true;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

TForm1.h

```
#ifndef TForm1H
#define TForm1H
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
#include <FMX.Controls.hpp>
#include <FMX.Forms.hpp>
#include <FMX.Controls.Presentation.hpp>
#include <FMX.StdCtrls.hpp>
#include <FMX.Types.hpp>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TForm1 : public TForm
{
__published:    // IDE-managed Components
    TPanel *Form1Pn;
    TButton *Button1;
    void __fastcall Button1Click(TObject *Sender);
private:    // User declarations
public:     // User declarations
    __fastcall TForm1(TComponent* Owner);
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
extern PACKAGE TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

TForm2.cpp

```
#include <fmx.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "TForm2.h"
#include "TForm3.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.fmx"
TForm2 *Form2;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm2::TForm2(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

//inizializza la form
void __fastcall TForm2::FormInit()
{
    Form3->Form3Layout->Parent = Form2Pn;
    Form3->Form3Layout->Visible = true;
    Form3->Show();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm2::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
  FormInit();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

TForm2.h

```
#ifndef TForm2H
#define TForm2H
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
#include <FMX.Controls.hpp>
#include <FMX.Forms.hpp>
#include <FMX.Controls.Presentation.hpp>
#include <FMX.Layouts.hpp>
#include <FMX.StdCtrls.hpp>
#include <FMX.Types.hpp>
#include <FMX.Objects.hpp>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TForm2 : public TForm
{
__published:    // IDE-managed Components
    TLayout *Form2Layout;
    TLabel *Label1;
    TLabel *Label2;
    TLabel *Label3;
    TLabel *Label4;
    TPanel *Form2Pn;
    TButton *Button1;
    TRectangle *Rectangle1;
    void __fastcall Button1Click(TObject *Sender);
private:    // User declarations
public:     // User declarations
    __fastcall TForm2(TComponent* Owner);
    //inizializza la form
    void __fastcall FormInit();
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
extern PACKAGE TForm2 *Form2;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

TForm3.cpp

```
#include <fmx.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "TForm3.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.fmx"
TForm3 *Form3;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm3::TForm3(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

TForm3.h

```
#ifndef TForm3H
#define TForm3H
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
#include <FMX.Controls.hpp>
#include <FMX.Forms.hpp>
#include <FMX.Controls.Presentation.hpp>
#include <FMX.StdCtrls.hpp>
#include <FMX.Types.hpp>
#include <FMX.Layouts.hpp>
#include <FMX.Objects.hpp>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TForm3 : public TForm
{
__published:    // IDE-managed Components
    TCheckBox *CheckBox1;
    TCheckBox *CheckBox2;
    TCheckBox *CheckBox3;
    TCheckBox *CheckBox4;
    TRectangle *Rectangle1;
    TLayout *Form3Layout;
private:    // User declarations
public:     // User declarations
    __fastcall TForm3(TComponent* Owner);
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
extern PACKAGE TForm3 *Form3;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example, including the content of the .dfm files.  Your question doesn't appear to have enough information to determine the problem.  Also note that with FireMonkey, any control can contain another, so you don't need a `TPanel` to hold the other form.  Also, `Show();` is the same as `Visible = True;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say: *When I click the button in Form1, Form2 appears inside Form1Pn as expected.*

That is not correct, as it is only content of `Form2` that appears in `Form1Pn`. You never call `Form2.Show`, which would show `Form2`, but outside of `Form1`.

In the call to show `Form3` contents you do call `Form3.Show` and it is therefore shown, but outside of `Form2` and without content as that has been "parented" to `Form2Pn`.

[image]

Comment: I don't call Form2.Show just because I did not need it since the visual result was OK but I admit that I did not know that I was seeing just the content of Form2 and not Form2 itself. On the other side, if I don't call Form3.Show I see nothing al all but if I call Form3.Show, Form3 appears outside Form1 with all its content, not empty as in your image.

Comment: Then your actual code doesn't match what you wrote in the question. The code you show: `Form3->Form3Layout->Parent = Form2Pn;` specifically moves the `Form3->Form3Layout` (the orange area) to `Form2Pn`.

Comment: I have updated the post with the actual code

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem.

Thanks Tom that you poined out that what I was seeing inside the panel was just the content of the form and not the form.

In my Form3 the Form3Layout was not the container of all other objects in the Form3 as the Form2Layout of Form2 was for the objects in Form2.

So I re-designed Form3 putting as first element the TLayout and all the other objects over it and this solved the problem.

(and I don't need to call Form3.Show)